# is it possible (and how) to add a type contract check for C++ template function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, types, typeclass

For example, I want to implement my own generic sort function, I want to require the type that would be passed in to be `Indexable`, and the element inside would be `Comparable`

```
template <typename Cont>
    **type_check: Cont is Indexable, Cont::Element is Comparable**
void my_sort(Cont& cont){
    // do sorting work
}
```

When I do `my_sort(vector<int>{1,6,5,4})` would be okay

But when do `my_sort(linkedlist<int>{1,6,5,4})` would fail me at Compile/Runtime, because `linkedlist` is not `Indexable`.

So is there a way to do such kind of type contract programming?

P.S.  I am in C++ 11 environment, but any Solution in later version of C++ is also welcomed

Comment: You are looking for [Concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints). or before [SFINAE.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Comment: Nice! but it's in C++20 or later

Comment: It is possible, but you need to define first what your concepts like `Indexable` mean. For instance, is `Indexable` just anything that has a `operator[]`? Or perhaps you prefer to tag specific types/containers explicitly?

Comment: @YanTing_ThePanda It will fail at compile time in either case. The only difference is whether you will have a nice user friendly error message ("Type Foo is not Comparable") or a wall of incomprehensible gibberish ("at (very long function name) instantiated from (another very long function name) instantiated from ... no suitable function  to call ... candidates are ... (10 pages of irrelevant barely different function signatures)".

Answer (score 2):

With SFINAE you can do something like:

```
template <typename Cont>
auto my_sort(Cont& cont)
-> decltype(cont[42], // Indexable
            void(), // That void to avoid evil overload of operator comma
            std::declval<Cont::Element>() < std::declval<Cont::Element>(), // Comparable
            void()) // That final void for the return type of sort
{
    // do sorting work
}
```

[`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is an alternative (to the `decltype`) if you have the traits ready.

Comment: Looks great, but what if we can't rely on checking the return value?

Comment: [std::experimental::is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) might be useful to create traits.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, once the [Concepts TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) makes its way into the C++ standard, you'll be able to do this with something like:

```
template <typename T>
concept Sortable = requires(T t) {
    { t[0] < t[0] } -> bool
};

template <Sortable Cont>
my_sort(Cont& cont) {
    // do sorting work
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5409fd92041ad07e)

An older version of the Concepts TS is implemented by GCC with the -fconcepts flag, but it won't be in the standard until C++20.  Until then, you can make do with SFINAE tricks:

```
template <typename Cont>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<decltype(std::declval<Cont>()[0] < std::declval<Cont>()[0]), bool>>
my_sort(Cont& cont) {
    // ...
}
```

This will fail to compile if, for a given `Cont c`, `c[0] < c[0]` is either not valid or not convertible to `bool`.
[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cbca9399260e408)